# xcode 5 ios simulator showing project apps

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating different projects in xcode 5, and used to run them in the IOS simulator and all works fine.

Suppose I am doing Projects A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

I found the situation that when I am running Project A, I can see the app icons of A, B, C, D, E in the simulator, while when I run Project F, it said the simulator is running and stopped me.

Then I close Project A, and run Project F again. This time, the simulator can run Project F, and I can see app icons of Projects D, E, F, G, H, I, J

I wonder there are 2 sets of simulator settings that show a particular sets of project icons, and how can I combine all of them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator is independent from the IDE. It depends on what iOS version you use. Each SDK version has its own simulator environment. Example: If you run projects A, B and C on the iOS 6.1 simulator, you will see all their icons in the home menu. When you then run D on (a fresh) iOS 7 simulator, you will only see the project D's icon in the simulator.

It might also depend on the display height (3.5" or 4"), but I am not sure about that.

Comment: your last assumption is correct, I ran the missing projects in the 4" simulator and all of them exist again.